# Why does Facebook navigation bar fixed and placed on top does not reload on moving to other pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was curious about this since a long time ago. When we click on any link in the page, like security page or even a person's name or inbox, the url changes but the navigation bar remains as it is. It does not reload but the rest of the page does, I know things like this can be done using Jquery and by changing the elements of display  but how does the url change too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a combination of AJAX and the `history.pushState()` method which allows you to update the URL and manipulate the browser's history:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState()_method